# Efficient way to assign list elements to numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have some numpy array objects in a list that I want to combine to a single numpy array. What is an efficient way to do this? The code below does not work since it puts a list into a numpy array...

```py
import numpy as np


C = [np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([4,5,6]), np.array([7,8,9])]

M = np.zeros((1,3*3))

M[0] = C ## THIS THROWS AN ERROR
```

Comment: `np.concatenate(C)`?

Comment: `np.hstack(C)`?

Comment: Your assignment would work if you made `M = np.zeros((1,3,3))`.  The list is size 3, so the copy target has to have a size 3 dimension, not a size 9.  Not that there's anything wrong with the `concatenate` suggestions.

Comment: why not `M.flat[:] = C` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
print(np.append(C,[]))

[1. 2. 3. 4. 5. 6. 7. 8. 9.]
```

Comment: `np.append` is a poorly named front end to `np.concatenate`.  Don't use it.  But feel free to look at it's code.